# Unable to install Devtools package for R studio mounted on linux redhat server

Tags: linux, r, redhat, rcurl, devtools

I'm unable to install the `devtools` package in R Studio on a redhat linux server. These error messages showed up:

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/home/xx/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RCurl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependency ‘RCurl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/xx/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.0/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘RCurl’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
```

I can't install the `RCurl` package too. I've tried to install the `libcurl` libraries too:

```
sudo yum install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo yum install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

But the system says no such packages are available available.

Is there any other way to install the `devtools` package? Or how can I resolve the `Rcurl` installation issue?

Comment: there are a list of RCurl configuration fails here: http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html

Comment: latest update:
I tried to install the libcurl development library but it says there's no such package available

sudo yum install libcurl4-gnutls-dev

sudo yum install libcurl4-openssl-dev

both of these commands were executed but the system says no such packages are available

Comment: latest update:
the locate libcurl command tells me that libcurl 7.19.7 latest version is already installed. But I still get error messsages in R when I try to install RCurl, like "Cannot find curl-config" and

"ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’"

Answer (score 5):

Resolved!

Just need to install *curl-config*

Comment: great! Here is how to do it in linux: `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev librtmp-dev`