# Error installing RCurl as part of devtools for R in Linux

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, libcurl, rcurl

To preface, I am fairly new to Linux.  I installed R 3.1.1 (the most recent version) on a Linux Server (Ubuntu 12.10, Quantal Quetzal), and am trying to install the devtools package in R.  When I run the `install.packages("devtools")` command, I receive the following error:

```
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
...
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried all of the commands from the other relevant StackOverflow answers (see bottom of post), but none of them worked.  For example, if I type `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`, I get the following error:

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main libssl-doc all 1.0.1c-3ubuntu2.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1c-3ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
...
Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've tried running `apt-get update` but that didn't allow me to install libcurl either.

Here's my sources.list file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates universe

deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu quantal/
deb-src http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu quantal/
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu raring/
deb-src http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu raring/
```

I tried changing 'archive' to 'old-releases' in sources.list, but it could not find any of the libcurl libraries: libcurl4-openssl-dev, libcurl4-nss-dev, or libcurl4-gnutls-dev.

I also tried installing Curl 7.37.1 [from source](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html), and it installed correctly.  Doing that allowed me to install the RCurl package but then I receive an error when trying to use the install_github() function within R: `install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv')`:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem with libcurl, RCurl, devtools, or my older Linux distro.  Not sure where to go from here.  Here are the related questions I've consulted:

[Problems installing the devtools package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923209/problems-installing-the-devtools-package)

["Non Zero Exit Status" R 3.0.1 'XML' and 'RCurl'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671814/non-zero-exit-status-r-3-0-1-xml-and-rcurl)

[Unable to install Devtools package for R studio mounted on linux redhat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236726/unable-to-install-devtools-package-for-r-studio-mounted-on-linux-redhat-server)

Comment: try `yum -y install libcurl libcurl-devel` if you have not done so yet. it worked for me last week after installing `su -c 'yum install R R-core R-core-devel R-devel'`

Comment: I receive `yum: command not found` to the command `su -c 'yum install R R-core R-core-devel R-devel'`. Sorry if this is basic but I'm pretty new to linux

Comment: try apt-get instead of yum

Comment: I receive an error (see below).  Do I need to add something to my sources.list or upgrade Ubuntu to a newer version or something?  `E: Unable to locate package R
E: Unable to locate package R-core
E: Unable to locate package R-core-devel
E: Unable to locate package R-devel`