# How to install R on RedHat

Tags: r, redhat

Stuck at configuration trying to install R from source on RedHat. Here is the output:

```
checking libcurl version ... 7.49.1
checking curl/curl.h usability... yes
checking curl/curl.h presence... yes
checking for curl/curl.h... yes
checking if libcurl is version 7 and >= 7.28.0... yes
checking if libcurl supports https... no
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https
```

I try `yum install libcurl4-openssl-dev` to solve the error,but the system says no such packages are available.

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2309887

Comment: Yes. but my OS is redhat not ubuntu,I try to install the packages that post mentioned, but  the system says no such packages are available.

Comment: Try to install `curl-config`

Comment: `curl-config` can be found in the  installation directory.

Comment: Ok, I just read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236726/unable-to-install-devtools-package-for-r-studio-mounted-on-linux-redhat-server) ... perhaps there are more answers

Comment: An RPM should be available for both fedora and RHEL. According to the help file, `sudo yum install R` should be sufficient on Fedora, or take a look at http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL for RHEL.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the devel package for libcurl, it worked in my case. Below is the command:

`yum install libcurl-devel.x86_64`